# Vue user object is null even though it is defined and shown in log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm calling a function that uses a person's user name to find the current User in my database. When I log the current user in my function, it works fine, but after that it says it null or undefined whenever i try to access it.

In my mounted:

```
mounted() {
    this.getCurrentUser(this.currentUserName);
    console.log(this.currentUser)

  }
```

In my getCurrentUser():

```
getCurrentUser(currentUserName){
        UserDataService.getCurrentUser(currentUserName)
            .then(response => {
               this.currentUser = response.data;
               console.log(this.currentUser);
            })
              .catch(e => {
              console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

In my UserDataService:

```
getCurrentUser(userName){
        return http.get("/users?userName="+userName);
     }
```

[This is when it is logged inside of the getCurrentUser function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLWHa.png)

Otherwise, it is null after i LOG it in mounted().

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make an async call. The result of `getCurrentUser` is not available right away.

The log in the method waits for that, but in `mounted` you don't wait.

You can make `mounted` async and wait for the result, but you'll have an `empty` component in the mean time.

```
async mounted() {
    await this.getCurrentUser(this.currentUserName);
    console.log(this.currentUser)
}
```

and return the promise from `getCurrentUser`

```
getCurrentUser(currentUserName){
   return UserDataService.getCurrentUser(currentUserName)
```